# (TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer) caused within django based app

Tags: python, numpy

It appears that this line of code is causing an error

```
alpha_1  = ( (100e-2 - q) * gamma_air)
```

the reason behind using 100e-2 and not 1 is because I though 1 - q(which is 
 a small number) is causing this error but it isnt

the value of q is 20946 * 1e-6
 the value of gamma_air is also a small number in the range of 0.01 - 0.09
  (at the last iteration of the loop, gamma_air = 0.0325)

I wish I can post the whole block of code, but I dont think I am allowed to do so.

Comment: Why do you think that line of code is causing the problem? Do you have a traceback you can show us? Because there doesn't seem to be anything there that would require interpreting a float64 as an integer.

Comment: When I commented it out everything worked fine

Comment: changing that line of code to this  ( (100e-2 - q) * float(gamma_air)) fixed the problem.... But I still dont understand what caused this problem

Comment: 100e-2 can be written as 1.0. There is no magic in this world any more.

Comment: What are the types and sizes of q and gamma?

Comment: You shouldn't be posting the whole code, but instead contriving a minimal example that will reproduce the error you're seeing. I'd guess that gamma is a numpy scalar which coerces alpha into a numpy type, which then causes a problem in a part of the code you're not able to show us. Perhaps code that asks something like `if isinstance(x, float)`.

Comment: gamma_air is supposed to be a  float taken from a numpy matrix "gamma_air  = _1_abroad[index_for_multi_array][i-1]"  which seems to be the problem.. I check the type of q which was float64, and the type of gamma_air is string.

Comment: Then you should look at `_1_abroad.dtype` and `_1_abroad.shape` to understand what that data looks like.